# How to represent the possible values for a property in a class member/enumeration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, rubygems

I am accessing a web service, which returns data as XML that gets populated into a custom model.  One of the nodes is called AccountType, and has 2 child nodes, Code, and Description.

So, coming back from the web service, it looks like this:

```
...
<AccountType>
  <Code>ABC</Code>
  <Description>Description for ABC</Description>
</AccountType>
...
```

Once it's transferred into the custom model, those values can then be accessed programmatically from an instance of the Account class like so:

```
myAccount.account_type_code
=> ABC
myAccount.account_type_description
=> Description for ABC
```

There is a small amount of possible values for account types, and i need to be able to program logic based on what account type an account is associated with.  So i'd like to enumerate the possible values within the Account class, with the goal of being able to write code that looks something like this:

```
if (myAccount.account_type_code == Account.account_types.ABC)
  ...do something...
end
```

Another aspect that is complicating things for me here is the fact that there is Code and Description associated with account type, so that a definition of the enumeration may need to look something like this:

```
def self.account_classes
  {
    :ABC => { :code=>"ABC", :description=>"Description for ABC" }
    ,:DEF => { :code=>"DEF", :description=>"Description for DEF" }
  }
end
```

which would then require logic to look like this:

```
if (myAccount.account_type_code == Account.account_types[:ABC][:code])
  ...do something...
end
```

Realistically, logic will only depend on the Code, but having the Description stored with it may be useful for test/user messages.

This functionality is part of a gem which will be used by multiple applications with different databases, so i'd prefer to stay away from a database solution.

---

EDIT

For simplicity, i only listed one property that acts like this (account type), but there are actually 3 or 4 different properties that all follow the same pattern (so also account class, account status, etc.).

---

Any thoughts much appreciated!

Comment: Personally, if the codes aren't that many, I would create N small classes which hardcode their fields. And then you can take advantage of Ruby's syntax, like this: `myAccount.is_a?(AbcAccount)`. If the classes are many, you can just code-generated the. There's rarely a reason to emulate class inheritance when you can actually have it. Also, if the values change dynamically, that can be helped as well. Ask for details if you can't figure it out, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: I edited the question to add that there are multiple properties like this; i guess my original intent to simplify the question actually omitted an important aspect.  This changes the recommendation towards inheritance, no? Thanks for your time, i appreciate!

Comment: Still, this doesn't say much. I would like to have an understanding what exactly are you trying to achieve and why using if/else statements is too much for you. You can always make wrapper methods like `acct.is_type?(:ABC)` or `acct.is_status?(:paid)`. If instead you are aiming for some sort of polymorphism, please state your requirements.

Comment: No, not looking for polymorphism at this point, but i suppose it cannot be ruled out further down the road.  Main goal here was to balance convenience and abstraction in checking the account type/class/status with the fact that these properties have both a Code and a Description.  If they did not have Description, then a simple symbol representation would have been my route, but i may have overthought it a bit.  Going to use a combination of my 'complex enumeration' implementation, and your wrapper methods.  If you want to submit an answer, i'll mark it, otherwise i'll answer - thanks again!

Comment: Sure. Working on it right now. You'll have it shortly.

Comment: Have you considered creating database tables for the lists of possible values, and their descriptions?

Comment: @WayneConrad, yes there's a comment in the original question: "This functionality is part of a gem which will be used by multiple applications with different databases, so i'd prefer to stay away from a database solution." Thanks though!

Comment: @ilanso, Please pardon me--I should have read better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am still not sure I understand your exact requirements, I will just throw what I would write right away if faced with your problem.

```
class Account
  attr_accessor :type
  @@types = [:ABC, :DEF, :GHI]
  @@types_to_codes = {:ABC => "ABC", :DEF => "DEF", :GHI => "GHI"}
  @@types_to_descriptions = {:ABC => "Description for ABC", :DEF => "Description for DEF", :GHI => "Description for GHI"}

  def self.code_for(type)
    @@types_to_codes[type]
  end

  def self.description_for(type)
    @@types_to_descriptions[type]
  end

  def self.valid_type?(t)
    @@types.include?(t)
  end

  def is_type?(t)
    self.type == t
  end

  def description
    self.class.description_for(self.type)
  end
end
```

To be perfectly fair to your problem, if I have an ahead knowledge of what are all the properties you need such code for, I would go even further: I would code-generate those, in the same manner as there are libraries who code-generate proxies for pieces of data coming from web services. If you would like an example, I'll be happy to provide you with one. Ruby really makes it extremely easy to do such things.

*As a side note: you could also add a constructor to the `Account` class which takes a Nokogiri XML fragment and fills the account fields from it.*

I hope this helps you somewhat.